Prove or disprove that the matrix equation of the form $AX+XA^{-T}=0$ has a nonsingular anti-symmetric solution $X$
I’m trying to prove that for $A=J_n(i)$, that is, the Jordan block matrix corresponding to the eigenvalue $i$ of size $n$, where $n$ is even, the matrix equation $AX+XA^{-T}=0$ has a nonsingular anti-symmetric solution $X$.
I have tried it on small values of $n (= 2,4,6)$ by brute force computations and proved that it is true.
Any ideas on how can I prove this for an arbitrary even $n$? Ideas or suggestions would suffice. Thank you so much!

Is $i$ here a square root of $-1$?

@FedorPetrov yes

If you denote $X_{pq}=(-i)^{p+q}Y_{pq}$, then the equations are $Y_{p+1,q+1}=Y_{p+1,q}+Y_{p,q+1}$ for $p, q=1,\dots,n$, here $Y_{kl} =0$ by definition if $\max(k, l) >n$. So you may put $Y_{pq}=0$ for $p+q>n+1$, $Y_{pq}=(-1)^p$ when $p+q=n+1$, $Y_{pp}=0$, and then define the elements on diagonals $p+q=n$, then $p+q=n-1$, etc.

Okay, I will just take time to process this information. Thank you so much!

To the person who downvoted this answer, care to explain why?

@WhiteCat Why are you interested? In general, on SE one should be able to downvote without the need to explain anything.

@FedericoPoloni of course there is no need to explain, but maybe downvote means that there is something wrong with the answer that should be fixed?
